# Why isn't this specific monkey-patching override work in my Python shell (CJSH)

Tags: python, shell, emacs, python-3.x, monkeypatching

I have an experimental shell at http://JonathansCorner.com/cjsh, intended among other things to reduce time finding files buried in heirarchies, and to [imperfectly] allow limitless Python customization the way EMACS allows limitless Lisp customization.

I've refactored it first to remove functions that would limit the user's ability to set variables that would outlive an exec(), and then refactored in other functions in a way intended to provide hooks for monkey-patching.

I have succeeded in defining and calling new functions, and I have succeeded in monkey-patching other areas besides one of the most obvious ways to monkey-patch the shell, to override the function that prompts the user for input so the user can have a customized prompt. The function for this is use_main_prompt(), and I have never overridden it to do anything other than its customizable behavior.

The enduser syntax, if you want to play with the CJSH shell, is that indented lines are Python lines and unindented lines are shell lines.

Is there anything I am doing in http://JonathansCorner.com/cjsh/download.cgi that would prevent fresh rebinding of that call? Is there anything I can do to say "Look it up from scratch, please?"

Answer (score 0):

Monkey patching functions causes changes to scopes in the original context.  To test this, try creating two different files and monkey patching them:

`something.py`:

```
def patchable_function():
    return "I have not been patched yet"

def another_function():
    return patchable_function()
```

`else.py`

```
import something
from something import another_function

print another_function() # "I have not been patched yet"
something.patchable_function = lambda : "I AM PATCHED!"
print another_function() # "I AM PATCHED!"
```